# Matlab - How can I get class attributes for all objects at once, without a for loop?

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of code like below:

```
points = num2cell(1:NoPs);
for i=1:NoPs
        points{i} = PL(i); 
        NNgbr_list(i) = length(points{i}.neighbors);
    end
```

Above, I'm collecting the length of the attribute "neighbors" (1 x m array) in a cell to be used later. Now, imagine that there are around 10 more attributes that I have to collect in separate arrays just like neighbors. My code is optimized for GPU computing but this bit here is slowing it down massively as expected.

Is there a way to get all the class attributes for a collection of objects at once? Like, I would like to collect "neighbors" in a 3D array for all points, and then another attribute in another 3D matrix and so on.

Comment: if you want to speed that up, use `numel` instead of `length`. `length` is slow. Also, preallocate `NNgbr_list`, you're growing it every loop iteration, which slows down the code tremendously. Preallocate points using `points = cell(1,NoPs)`, which is simpler and faster. Though I don't know why you want to have that cell array, `PL` is quite a bit more useful than `points`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you. I got rid of the `points` cell and the for loop. It looks better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work to do simply:

```
cat(3, PL.neighbors)
```

The expression `PL.neighbors` will return a "comma-separated list" which you can then concatenate.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks. I have a small problem with this technique though. The size of "neighbors" changes for each object in `PL`. To solve this, I initialize the global neighbors matrix as `neighbors = zeros(1,NNgbr_max,NoPs,'gpuArray')`. `NNgbr_max` is one of the object's number of columns with the maximum amount. Then, I use a for loop to assign the values to each point with `neighbors(1,1:NNgbr,i) = PL(i).neighbors`.  Is there any way to slice each of them separately with a one liner instead of a for loop? If not, I may have to do this on CPU then transfer it to GPU.

Comment: If the properties are different sizes in that way, whatever you do isn't going to be terribly efficient, so I think you're going to have to live with a loop there. It would probably be faster to do this rearrangement on the CPU and then make a single copy to the GPU.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much. You saved me a lot of time.